# Coffescript switch when

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, dashing

My coffeescript is as following:

```
level = switch
      when 0 <= value <= 1 then 0
      when 1 < value <= 2 then 1
      when 2 < value <= 3 then 2
      when 3 < value <= 4 then 3
      when 4 < value <= 5 then 4
      else 6
```

Why do I get :

> Uncaught Error: ExecJS::ProgramError: [stdin]:15:4: error: unexpected
>   when    when 1 < value <= 2 then 1

This works fine:

```
 when value <= cool then 0
      when value >= warm then 4
      else 
        bucketSize = (warm - cool) / 3 # Total # of colours in middle
        Math.ceil (value - cool) / bucketSize
```

This also works:

```
 level = switch
      when value <= 1 then 0
      when value <= 4 then 4
      else 5
```

untill I add 
when value <=2 then 1

Comment: It seems to be correct. I tried it in the coffeeScript page and works. Make sure it is not an ExecJS problem or anything else.

Comment: @Matias I am using dashing. how to find if it is execjs problem?

Comment: Sounds like your not compiling the coffeescript to javascript before running it.

Comment: sintra compiles it i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all about indentation.

```
level = switch
      when 0 <= value < 1 then 0
      when 1 <= value < 2 then 1
      when 2 <= value < 3 then 2
      when 3 <= value < 4 then 3
      when 4 <= value <= 5 then 4
      else 5
```

I kept the code here : http://www.coffeelint.org/

and then checked the indentation.

Comment: @AJFarmar when I pasted the code in lint it showed that there was indentation problem.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer so the question is closed? Thanks.